# Unexpected CSS Animation behaviour in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I have the following HTML:

```
<p class="animate">X</p>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.animate {
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-name: add-icon;
    font-size: 8em;
}

@keyframes add-icon {
    0% {
        font-size: 18em;
    }
    25% {
        font-size: 6em;
    }
    60% {
        font-size: 13em;
    }
    100% {
        font-size: 8em;
    }
}
```

This is what I expect to see: (tested in Firefox, Chrome, Edge)

[image: Expected Behaviour]

But this is how it actually behaves in Safari 11:

[image: Actual Behaviour]

I tried to prefix my CSS with the Webkit prefixes but that doesn't change the result.

[Here's a working demo of my problem.](https://codepen.io/maracuja-juice/pen/paBzyW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rem` instead of `em`

Actually `em` depends on the parent element and `rem` depends on the root element...so its good to use `rem` instead of `em`.

> ***[Read this article](https://zellwk.com/blog/rem-vs-em/)***

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.animate {
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-name: add-icon;
  font-size: 8rem;
}

@keyframes add-icon {
  0% {
    font-size: 18rem;
  }
  25% {
    font-size: 6rem;
  }
  60% {
    font-size: 13rem;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 8rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="animate">X</p>
```

Comment: Oooh! Thank you, that solves it. Need to learn more about that rem/em.
I wonder though why this issue only in Safari and not in other browsers.

Comment: Hmm and the article says: `Size in em if the property scales according to it’s font-size`

Comment: So shouldn't `em` be more appropriate / can this also be solved with `em`?

Comment: @maracuja-juice I am not sure about this...I think safari does no support em fully...I was doing some research but didn’t find something helpful...I will post something if I found....

Comment: Have you every found anything out about this?